# Text classification using Java

Tags: nlp, machine-learning, ontology, dbpedia

I need to categorize a text or word to a particular category. For example, the text 'Pink Floyd' should be categorized as 'music' or 'Wikimedia' as 'technology' or 'Einstein' as 'science'.

How can this be done? Is there a way I can use the [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/) for the same? If not, the database has to be trained from time to time, right?

Comment: Machine learning is only really going to help you here if the terms are used in context otherwise it's a basic dictionary lookup task with maybe some fuzzy guessing to match misspellings and "einstein" vs "Albert Einstein" issues. Where are you getting your terms that you need to categorize? Reading text or just a big list of terms?

Comment: Reading text, Thien. I'll just extract probably nouns and adjectives from sentences and categorize the text based on these terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [text classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification) problem. [Manning, Raghavan and Schütze's Information Retrieval book chapter](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/text-classification-and-naive-bayes-1.html) is a nice introduction. I think you do not need DBPedia nor NER for this, just a small labeled training data set with enough labeled examples for all of your classes.

Comment: is there any tutorial that I can follow to apply this model ?

Comment: Try week 3 of the Stanford online NLP course: https://class.coursera.org/nlp/lecture/preview

Answer (score 3):

Yes, DBpedia may be a good choice for this kind of problem. You'll have to

1. squash the DBpedia category structure so you get the right granularity (e.g., Pink Floyd is listed under `Capitol Records artists` and a host of other categories, but not directly under `Music`). Maybe pick a few large categories and try to find whether your concepts are listed indirectly in them;
2. normalize text; Einstein is listed as `Albert Einstein`, not `einstein`
3. deal with ambiguity due to terms describing multiple concepts and concepts belonging to multiple top-level categories.

These problems may be solvable using machine learning, but I only see how it can be done if you extract these terms, along with relevant features, from running text. But in that case, you might just as well classify the entire text into one of the categories you choose in step 1.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but how do i go about..categorizing the dbpedia structure? like you said, it's not under categories that i would prefer. I guess it works fine if i want to query random data.

Comment: @Madhura: DBpedia has categories `Music` and `Science` near the top of its hierarchy. You'll have to use some graph algorithms to find them.

Answer (score 1):

This is the well-studied [named entity recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition) problem. Unless you have a particular need to roll your own technology (hint: it's a hard problem in general), using [Gate](http://gate.ac.uk/), or perhaps one of the online services that builds on it (e.g. TSO's [Data Enrichment Service](http://openup.tso.co.uk/des)),  would be a good option. An alternative online service is [OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com/about/developer).

Comment: Actually, named-entity recognition/classification is the task of doing this in running text and is generally done with much broader categories.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mapping your categries to DBPedia.
2. Index with lucene selected DBPedia categories and label data with your category names.
3. Do search for your data - tokenization, normalization will be done by Lucene.

This approach is somehow related to KNN classification.

Comment: Are you saying index all the categories by building a Lucene `Document` out of the subcategories and article titles in each? If so, that would be a bit similar to kNN, yes. I did something somewhat similar for my thesis research, although on different data, and it did work.

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly. I was using to creating semantic space of Wikipedia categories, it was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes DBpedia is a good choice for text classification, as you can use its predicates/ relations to query and to extract the meaningful information for the particular category.

You can look into the endpoint for querying Dbpedia:
http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Further, learn the basic syntax of SPARQL to query on the endpoint from the following link:
http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/